# UINavigationController and viewWillDisappear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

So I have a UINavController in my app and am trying to execute a method when the user presses the back button.  I have searched everywhere and can only find bits and pieces that don't really make sense out of context.

Is there a way to implement some sort of check that catches when the user presses the back button to dismiss the current view?  (the viewWillDisappear method for the view being popped never gets called for some reason.  I did read that it doesn't unless you forward that call?)  Does that sound right, and does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, if you add a UINavigationController to a UIView via code, it won't send those messages to it's subviews by default. It will only do this if the UINavigationController received these calls itself. Maybe this is your problem (I don't know your view setup).

So, when adding the view of the UINavigationController, be sure to manually send it these messages.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

[navigationController viewWillAppear:NO];
[aView addSubview:navigationController.view];
[navigationController viewDidAppear:NO];
```

At least, this is what I found during development. Been searching for this for a long time and I still don't understand the rationale behind it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might be something like this, I am going to give this a shot and let you know if it's right.

Comment: I checked and it worked for me. Two minor corrections, this line **[navigationController viewWillAppear:NO];** should be put after the **addView** method. And I don't think the **viewDidAppear** method is necessary.

Comment: But the whole point of a "will" event is that it happens before you take the action, so I don't think your correction is valid.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. There are the only two methods that get called when a UIViewController is pushed to the navigation controller stack. Similarly, if one is being pushed then something probably was just popped. This is what I did to call viewDidDisappear and viewWillDisappear.

```c
# pragma mark - UINavigationControllerDelegate Methods

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    static UIViewController *vcPointer = nil;

    // If the previous view controller is still around then let's send a viewWillDisappear message
    if (vcPointer != nil) {
        if ([vcPointer respondsToSelector:@selector(viewWillDisappear:)]) {
            [vcPointer viewWillDisappear:animated];
        }
    }

    // Keep track of a pointer to the current viewController
    vcPointer = viewController;

    [viewController viewWillAppear:animated];   
}
```

This code keeps a pointer reference to the last view controller that was pushed so that once we push another one we can pop the last one (if it still exists).

Answer (score 0):

You can always hide the default back navigation button and create your own with its own method to be called when pressed.

Execute whatever code you want there then pop the view.

Comment: I don't explicitly need to change the functionality as that works perfectly as is.  I just need to execute a method when a certain view inside the navController pops off...

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution:

- Add a custom button on the left side in the navigation bar
- Let that button activate a custom method.

Disadvantage of this workaround: you will lose that nice arrow shaped "back" button. That can be solved as well with a custom image.

So here is my code.
Put this in your viewDidLoad:

```
// LeftButton in Navigation Bar
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonPushed:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
[leftBarButton release];
```

Then add this method in the same .m file:

```
- (void) backButtonPushed: (id)sender  {
// do what you want to do       
}
```

dont forget in the .h file

```
- (void) backButtonPushed: (id)sender;
```

Answer (score -1):

The viewWillDisappear & viewDidDisappear is called when a controller is popped or dismissed. The function is called on the fore-front view controller not on the UINavigationController itself. Did you possibly subclass and forget to call the super on something?

Comment: Yeah I thought so too.  A lot of the stuff I have been reading say otherwise though.