# UINavigationController back button press and viewWillDisappear

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've got a chat app and I simply want to let the connection manager to leave the current chatroom when the back button on my `UINavigationController` is pressed (or the view is left in any other way).
`viewWillDisappear:` isn't working for me.

Unlike some others with issues ( [UINavigationController and viewWillDisappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072192/uinavigationcontroller-and-viewwilldisappear) for instance) I have what should be a totally textbook view setup - one `UINavigationController`, leading into a bunch of subclassed `UIViewControllers` connected by segues.  What can I do to detect when I leave the chatroom view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's set up ok ? I just made a new project with the Master-Detail template in Xcode, I added this to my detail view controller, and when I pressed back button, "gone..." was logged as expected...

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    NSLog(@"gone...");
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure - it's is a view to which the only segue is a manually triggered one (called in code).  Still, i would expect viewWillDisappear to be called because I've done no extraneous setup.

Comment: Would the fact that I started as a single view application change anything?  Like make the environment not call view change stuff?

Comment: So you've still got a problem? Do you have a repo for it? Maybe I can take a look

Answer (score 1):

Xcode autocomplete got me!

`- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` works fine
For some reason Xcode also suggests

`- (void)viewWillDisappear`
Which does NOT work!

Same as here:
[viewDidDisappear not getting called on a UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186309/viewdiddisappear-not-getting-called-on-a-uinavigationcontroller?rq=1)